# Django-CMS template blocks

Tags: python, django, templates, django-cms

Is there any solution to provide "template blocks" from database for django-cms.
I want to generate the template befor django-cms renders the placeholder template tags.

It should be possible to create the blocks in django-admin, sort them and give them to the django-cms.

This is what i would use for the blocks and layout: http://designmodo.github.io/startup-demo/

Example for a template block in the database:

```
<div>{% placeholder test %}</div>
```

Any idea for that?

Comment: Use verbatim tag and render twice? Not very clear about you ask for.

Comment: I created a templatetag to output the html from the database like the example above.
Problems are: Render the placeholder tag(s) correctly, save plugins not working from there. 
Where do you recommend to use the verbatim tag?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Djangocms-stacks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangocms-stacks/).  They are incredibly flexible and though you will need to use the new Django CMS 3.0 as a requirement for it, the new CMS is really quite an amazing upgrade and very worth the effort.

[edit]
Just in case you don't see the details of the package that are relevant, stacks can contain other plugins, as well as other stacks. So, you could quite conceivably create a single template site that actually allows for complete control restructure of your layout from the edit interface.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do use the 3.0 dev version of django-cms. The thing is i want to create my template from the edit or admin interface. I want to **paste html-django-template-placeholder code** in a snipet plugin and fill the placeholders afterwards with plugins like text or images. That should give control over how many placeholder are available in each template block from the edit or admin interface. [Example (the plans, how many plans are there? 3 or 4 or ..)](http://designmodo.github.io/startup-demo/framework/samples/sample-03/index.html)

Comment: Or maybe there is an other better solution how to do that? Maybe a multifunctional plugin that i could use or something like that?

Comment: I am not sure how stacks won't resolve that need actually.  A stack is also a plugin and you can pre-create the stack with the components/plugins that you want quite easily.  However, I suspect you are also wanting to manage the CSS for placement/treatment as well.  For that, I would recommend a solution involving Django Compressor and template driven LESS so that you can automate/check the resultant CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to organize blocks inside a placeholder, but want to use the precast scaffolding techniques from your CSS framework, then have a look at https://github.com/jrief/djangocms-cascade
It requires DjangoCMS>=3.0.